# PowerShell doesn't export Length with Export-Csv cmdlet

Tags: powershell

So when I run Get-ChildItem on a directory the output will have "Length" however, when I then pipe to Export-Csv the output has a lot of additional information, but "Length" is no longer included for some reason.

Is there a way to make sure "Length" is incuded with all of the information that piping to Export-Csv provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export-Csv checks the first object in the pipeline and uses that as a base for column definitions. In your case, the first object was a folder which has no length property. Thus the results you get.

Try to filter to export files only ( `where { ! $_.PsIsContainer }` ).

You can also use Select-Object just before the export - it will add selected properties, and assign $null to those objects not having that property. The end result is more or less the same (and it's more bulletproof and allows more "picky" csv).

Comment: Alright, but for the Select-Object, I would have to list EVERY object I wanted correct?

Comment: Nah, select-object primary goal is to select properties of the object (similar to TSQL *SELECT* foo, bar FROM ...) and it accepts wildcards, so: `ls | select Name, Length, *Time*` would work just fine. And even if you get errors if you cross-select (e.g. `select Name, *`) you can ignore them (or silence with -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) because what they will tell you is that property mentioned before * is already there and can not be doubled.